# Simple CSS responsive touch menu issue with anchor link

Tags: css

Based on the code given on this website http://osvaldas.info/drop-down-navigation-responsive-and-touch-friendly it is easy to create a simple CSS drop down menu that is responsive and works on touch devices.

However, the code contains an anchor link to the nav, so if the nav isn't at the top of the page (and mine isn't - there is a logo above it) the browser scrolls down to the nav. This is disconcerting and not what I want. There must be a way to get this to work without the browser scrolling down?

I've put the code on JSF Fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/Ltebg0ah/ and below.

The issue is something to do with this (text from Osvaldas website):
CSS pseudo selector :target makes it easy to toggle menu as the anchor's href attribute coincides with CSS ID selector name. Therefore, as you might have understood, the first anchor of #nav > a is responsible for showing and the second for hiding the menu.

```
<div class="header"></div>  

<nav id="nav">
<a href="#nav" title="Show navigation">Menu</a>
<a href="#" title="Hide navigation">Close Menu</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="workshops.html">Workshops</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="news.html">News</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>

<div class="content">



 .header {
 height:200px;
background-color:brown;
 }

.content {
height:1000px;
background-color:green;
 }


#nav > a
{
    display: none;
}


#nav
{
    position: relative;
}
    #nav > a
    {
    }
    #nav:not( :target ) > a:first-of-type,
    #nav:target > a:last-of-type
    {
        display: block;
    }

/* first level */

#nav > ul
{
    height: auto;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
    #nav:target > ul
    {
        display: block;
    }
    #nav > ul > li
    {
        width: 100%;
        float: none;
    }
```

Comment: It is not possible since, the menu opens up when the #nav is targeted. It is not possible to make it without using JS.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can do this easily without Javascript. Just use a checkbox and 2 labels attached to it via the id. This way you can do it in pure css using the :checked pseudo selector.

http://jsfiddle.net/Ltebg0ah/3/

```css
 .header {
     height:200px;
    background-color:brown;
     }

.content {
    height:1000px;
    background-color:green;
     }


#nav
    {
        display: none;
    }
        #nav ~ label
        {
            display: none;
        }
        #nav:not( :checked ) ~ label:first-of-type,
        #nav:checked ~ label:last-of-type
        {
            display: block;
        }
 
    /* first level */
 
    #nav ~ ul
    {
        opacity: 0;
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        transition-duration: 0.4s;
    }
        #nav:checked ~ ul
        {
            opacity: 1;
        }
        #nav ~ ul > li
        {
            width: 100%;
            float: none;
        }
```

```html
<div class="header"></div> 

<nav>
    
    <input type="checkbox" id="nav" />
    <label for="nav">Show nav</label>
    <label for="nav">Hide nav</label>
  <ul>
   <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="workshops.html">Workshops</a></li>
   <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
   <li><a href="news.html">News</a></li>
   <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>


<div class="content"></div>
```

Comment: I have also added a nice little css transition for a smoother user experience. You can wipe that out and replace it by your display: none vs display: block method.

Comment: Why would anyone vote this down? This is a very elegant solution of the problem. A checkbox is even nice in a semantic sense here. Besides, using :checked helps in many cases where otherwise JS would be necessary.

Comment: I can't focus on this today, but what you've done appears to work, solves the problem, looks elegant and avoids me having to use JS (which I know nothing about). Thanks (it wasn't me who voted it down)

Comment: what does the wavy line symbol mean: #nav ~ label ?

Comment: ~ is the sibling selector, part of CSS3. It selects elements on the same DOM node level. The elements don’t have to be adjacent siblings, but they have to have the same parent. http://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/general-sibling-selector-css-selector/

Comment: If that solved your problem, it'd be nice if you could vote it back up. Thanks!

Comment: I would if I had the reputation points to do so. I'm new on here... Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

The reason the browser moves down is because you've specified an anchor for the menu to dropdown with an ID of `#nav`. The browser assumes it should focus on that section with the ID of `#nav` once clicked. Causing it to scroll down to that div.

You will need to use JavaScript to get the functionality you want. You can also use a fantastic HTML framework called [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com) which has that functionality plus much more that would make your development experience much easier. It's lightweight and has tons of features.

**You can view my [JSFIddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1xuuqrn1/1/) to see this functionality using [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com)**

I hope this helps.

Comment: Might it be possible for the link to go to an anchor on the header div (which is at the top of the page), while preserving the pseudo selector :target to toggle the menu. Maybe using a class on the nav div...

I've just given this a go and couldn't get it to work.

It seems like the toggle / target only works if the link is to the #nav div – i.e. if both share the same selector name.

Comment: No matter where you place the navigation menu, the browser will still focus on that div. With your current code, you can't really move it anywhere for it to not behave that way. You will simply have to use JavaScript or use a framework that already takes care of issues such as that.

Comment: See my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1xuuqrn1/1/) on how to accomplish this using [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com).

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'll look into Bootstrap, but as someone new to coding at the moment I prefer to write it myself, so I know what is happening.